# Set proxy for Android WebView

Tags: java, android, proxy, android-webview

I have been trying to set Proxy and use from android Webview but while loading site always return `net::error_timed_out`

I have used [NetCipher](https://github.com/guardianproject/NetCipher) and used normal System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", ip); methods and it always returns True 'means it connected successfully' but when i tried to run `webView.loadUrl(link);` it return `net::error_timed_out` and sometime the link i am trying to load , load successfully

Function i use:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private boolean setProxy(String host, String port) {
    Log.d("Debug", "Setting proxy with >= 4.4 API.");
    Context appContext = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port + "");
    try {
        Field loadedApkField = appContext.getClass().getField("mLoadedApk");
        loadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
        Object loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(appContext);
        Class loadedApkCls = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
        Field receiversField = loadedApkCls.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
        receiversField.setAccessible(true);
        ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) receiversField.get(loadedApk);
        for (Object receiverMap : receivers.values()) {
            for (Object rec : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()) {
                Class clazz = rec.getClass();
                if (clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")) {
                    Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);

                    onReceiveMethod.invoke(rec, appContext, intent);
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d("Debug", "Setting proxy with >= 4.4 API successful!");
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Connecting function :

```
     WebViewActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
//                    boolean worked = WebkitProxy.setProxy(MainActivity.class.getName(), getApplicationContext(), webView, proxyDomain, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort));
                    boolean worked = setProxy(proxyIP,proxyPort);
                    Log.d("Debug","IP = "+proxyIP+" ProxyPort = "+proxyPort + " worked= "+worked);
                    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                    webView.clearCache(true);
                   webView.clearHistory();
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                    webView.loadUrl(link);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Debug", "Could not start WebkitProxy " + e.getMessage() + " Number : "+number);
                }
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx.xxx">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: did you find any solution ?